# Javascript - Creating an array with FizzBuzz results using a pure recursive function

Tags: javascript, recursion

I am trying to get a better understanding of recursion and am thus trying create an array with numbers using the common 'Fizzbuzz' problem. I am trying to do this by implementing a pure recursive function with only one input, but I am having trouble getting my answer to appear in the correct order. I was also curious to know if there was a way to write a pure recursive function that would use push instead of concat in this situation. Any help is appreciated! I am able to print out the desired output, but am doing it in reverse order. Below is what I have so far:

```
 var fizzBuzz = function(n) {
    //create results array
    //create base case for when n === 1
    //recurse and push value to array
    var results = [];
  if (n === 1) {
    return '1';
  } else {
    if (n % 3 === 0 && n % 5 === 0) {
      results.push('FizzBuzz');
    } else if (n % 5 === 0) {
      results.push('Buzz');
    } else if (n % 3 === 0) {
      results.push('Fizz');
    } else {
      results.push(''+ n);
    }
    return results.concat(fizzBuzz(n - 1));
  }
};
```

Comment: You'll have to reverese the array at the end!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are many ways to do this and it depends on your requirements.

One of the easiest way is to reverse your array in the end:

```js
function fizzBuzz(n) {
  function fizzBuzzRecursive(n) {
    //create results array
    //create base case for when n === 1
    //recurse and push value to array
    var results = [];
    if (n === 1) {
      return '1';
    } else {
      if (n % 3 === 0 && n % 5 === 0) {
        results.push('FizzBuzz');
      } else if (n % 5 === 0) {
        results.push('Buzz');
      } else if (n % 3 === 0) {
        results.push('Fizz');
      } else {
        results.push(''+ n);
      }
      return results.concat(fizzBuzzRecursive(n - 1));
    }
  }
  
  return fizzBuzzRecursive(n).reverse();
};

console.log(fizzBuzz(15));
```

It may look ugly but it solves your problem with minimal changes in code (sometimes, it is a key requirement).

Another solution is to concat `fizzBuzzRecursive` to your `results` instead. Note that in order to make it work you need to return `[1]` instead of `"1"` for `n == 1`, so that JS interprets the first result as an array, not a string.

```js
function fizzBuzz(n) {
    //create results array
    //create base case for when n === 1
    //recurse and push value to array
    var results = [];
  if (n === 1) {
    return ['1']; // !
  } else {
    if (n % 3 === 0 && n % 5 === 0) {
      results.push('FizzBuzz');
    } else if (n % 5 === 0) {
      results.push('Buzz');
    } else if (n % 3 === 0) {
      results.push('Fizz');
    } else {
      results.push(''+ n);
    }
    return fizzBuzz(n - 1).concat(results);
  }
};

console.log(fizzBuzz(15));
```

The third solution is to change your recursive function so that it iterates in a reverse order. You may try it yourself :)

Comment: Thank you so much Yeldar! My goal was to implement a solution that did not utilize an inner function, so this was so helpful. Happy coding!

Answer (score 1):

I'm also working on learning recursion better right now and I took a crack at a recursive FizzBuzz solution before going to google to see how other people did it.

This doesn't use an array, but I haven't found another person with this solution so I figure I will share it here. Note that it does print an extra newline in the console before the result.

```
function fizzBuzz(n, result) {
  if (n === 0) {
    console.log(result);
    return;
  }
  if (n % 15 === 0) {
    result = '\nFizzBuzz' + (result ? result : '');
  }
  else if (n % 5 === 0) {
    result = '\nBuzz' + (result ? result : '');
  }
  else if (n % 3 === 0) {
    result = '\nFizz' + (result ? result : '');
  }
  else {
    result = '\n' + n + (result ? result : '');
  }
  return fizzBuzz(n - 1, result);
}
```

EDIT: Here is another version that uses a switch statement instead of if/else if. It also solves the extra newline problem of my previous solution.

```
function fizzBuzz(n, result = '') { // result initialized as an empty string the first time the function is called
  switch(true) {                    // this stops the first (last in order of being printed) entry from being entry + undefined
    case (n === 0):
      console.log(result.substring(1)); // prints the result without the extra \n at the beginning
      return;
    case (n % 15 === 0):
      result = '\nFizzBuzz' + result;
      break;
    case (n % 5 === 0):
      result = '\nBuzz' + result;
      break;
    case (n % 3 === 0):
      result = '\nFizz' + result;
      break;
    default:
      result = '\n' + n + result;
  }
  return fizzBuzz(n - 1, result);
}

fizzBuzz(15);
```

EDIT 2:

Here's the same as the second solution, but with string interpolation instead of concatenation. Cleaner in my opinion, but that's really just personal preference.

```
function fizzBuzz(n, result = '') { // result initialized as an empty string the first time the function is called
  switch(true) {                    // this stops the first (last in order of being printed) entry from being entry + undefined
    case (n === 0):
      console.log(result.substring(1)); // prints the result without the extra \n at the beginning
      return;
    case (n % 15 === 0):
      result = `\nFizzBuzz${result}`;
      break;
    case (n % 5 === 0):
      result = `\nBuzz${result}`;
      break;
    case (n % 3 === 0):
      result = `\nFizz${result}`;
      break;
    default:
      result = `\n${n}${result}`;
  }
  return fizzBuzz(n - 1, result);
}

fizzBuzz(20);
```

Comment: nice solution, perhaps your code would be even cleaner with a switch statement, do you think you could implement that? :)

Comment: Good idea! I just added a new version that has a switch statement. Not sure if it's what you had in mind :)

Answer (score 0):

Another solution which iterates from 0 (kinda): https://repl.it/FysV/1

```
var hold = 0;
var fizzBuzz = function(n) {
  var results = [];

  if(hold === n) return '' + n;

  if(hold === 0) {
    hold = n;
    n = 1;
  }

  if (n === 1) {
    results.push('1');
  } else if (n % 3 === 0 && n % 5 === 0) {
    results.push('FizzBuzz');
  } else if (n % 5 === 0) {
    results.push('Buzz');
  } else if (n % 3 === 0) {
    results.push('Fizz');
  } else {
    results.push(''+ n);
  }

  return results.concat(fizzBuzz(n + 1));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**First approach: passing the array as parametter**

```js
var fizzBuzz = function(n, arr = []) {   // fizzBuzz should have two params: the number n and the accumulated array arr
  
  // if you don't like the arr = [] in the parametter, or if it's not supported then just declare arr as a regular argument (function(n, arr)) and uncomment the following line to check if the array is passed or not (in the first call)
  // arr = arr || [];
  
  if (n === 1) {                         // if n is 1 then add 1 to the array and return its inverse because we didn't fuzzBuzz in the right order
    arr.push('1');
    return arr.reverse();
  } else {                               // logic blah blah ...
    if (n % 3 === 0 && n % 5 === 0) {
      arr.push('FizzBuzz');
    } else if (n % 5 === 0) {
      arr.push('Buzz');
    } else if (n % 3 === 0) {
      arr.push('Fizz');
    } else {
      arr.push('' + n);
    }
    return fizzBuzz(n - 1, arr);         // no need to use concat because we are passing the acummulated array to append to it
  }
}

console.log(fizzBuzz(10));
```

**Second approach: function inside function with clossures**

```js
var fizzBuzz = function(n) {
  var arr = [];                        // the array
  
  function fizzBuzzInternal(i) {       // the real fizzBuzz function
    if (i % 3 === 0 && i % 5 === 0) {  // logic blah blah ...
      arr.push('FizzBuzz');
    } else if (i % 5 === 0) {
      arr.push('Buzz');
    } else if (i % 3 === 0) {
      arr.push('Fizz');
    } else {
      arr.push('' + i);
    }
    
    if(i < n)                         // if i is still less than n then invoke another fizzBuzzInternal call
      fizzBuzzInternal(i + 1);
  }
  
  fizzBuzzInternal(1);                // invoke the first fizzBuzzInternal to start the show
  
  return arr;                         // return the array (no need for inversing because we fizzBuzzed in the right direction)
}

console.log(fizzBuzz(10));
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's another way that wasn't mentioned:

```
var fizzBuzz = function(n) {
  if (n < 1) return [];
  
  if (n % 3 === 0 && n % 5 === 0) {
    return fizzBuzz(n - 1).concat(['FizzBuzz']);
  } else if (n % 3 === 0) {
    return fizzBuzz(n - 1).concat(['Fizz']);
  } else if (n % 5 === 0) {
    return fizzBuzz(n - 1).concat(['Buzz']);
  } else {
    return fizzBuzz(n - 1).concat([`${n}`]);
  }
};
```